# openCV in Windows mobile

Tags: c#, c++, windows, mobile, opencv

I want to display camera output from a mobile phone (with Windows mobile OS) using openCV and C# / C++. If you have any useful link / code, please share in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the native API for doing this if you can, unless there's a specific reason you want to use OpenCV.

[Windows Mobile: using phone's camera with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082625/windows-mobile-using-phones-camera-with-c)

There's a couple of useful links on [this site](http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2007/07/camera-api-for-windows-mobile.html).

Comment: hi, thanks for your link. those links are really interesting, but I want to implement optical flow using mobile phone camera and train a model with that. that's why I was planning to use openCV. do you have any link where I will find information regarding how to use openCV on windows mobile?